# Firebase: Recuperar un padre pero con solo uno de sus hijos

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Tengo una BD Firebase con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de la rama `empresa` tengo una key por cada empresa, y dentro de cada una de ellas tengo una rama `tiendas` con una key para cada tienda.

Hasta ahora todo me funciona correctamente y puedo crear,borrar y modificar tanto empresas como tiendas.

Lo que necesito ahora es poder recuperar un `DataSnapShot` de una `empresa` con una única `tienda`.

Una forma de hacerlo sería recuperando la empresa con todas sus tiendas y luego recorrer el `DataSnapShot` hasta encontrar la tienda. Pero lo que me gustaría hacer es obtener el `DataSnapShot` únicamente de la empresa y con la tienda que me interesa, conociendo de antemano la key tanto de empresa como de la tienda.

¿Es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes aplicar varios tipos de filtro en RealTime Database, [revisa la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query), puede que haya algún tipo de filtro que aplique para este caso. Aunque me pregunto por qué no tienes un nodo `tiendas` aparte  y otro nodo para expresar las relaciones entre `empresa` y `tiendas`. Sea como sea, en las pruebas verifica siempre la cantidad de datos que traen tus consultas, puedes puede que para usar un solo dato estés trayendo decenas, miles o millones de datos y eso es particularmente peligroso en Firebase.

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano.  Precisamente, lo que quiero hacer son consultas lo más "ligeras" posibles, y que únicamente traigan aquellos datos que realmente voy a manejar. Consultaré más detenidamente la documentación a ver que encuentro.

Comment: El problema es que Firebase está montado sobre un modelo NoSQL, lo cual rompe los esquemas tradicionales de modelos de datos. Eso implica que a veces hay que aceptar tener datos duplicados como un mal menor, porque de lo contrario podrías tener los datos en un solo lugar, pero ciertas consultas por ese mismo motivo van a estar trayendo datos masivos (con todo lo que ello implica de consumo de banda, números de documentos leídos, etc). He leído posts sobre gente que se ha encontrado con una factura que da miedo en planes de pago. Por eso hay que pensar muy bien como vas a estructurar los datos.

Comment: En la documentación de Firebase hay algunos ejemplos donde ellos indican formas correctas y no correctas de estructurar los datos, con ejemplos sencillos pero que ayudan a comprender un poco el asunto. La cuestión es que cuando diseñas el modelo de datos tienes que tener un poco claro también qué tipo de consultas vas a lanzar sobre esos datos para decidir si te conviene agrupar de un modo o de otro. No recuerdo ahora el enlace, pero si buscar algo así como *Estructura de datos en Firebase*  lo encontrarás. Es muy importante que leas eso y comprendas el fondo del asunto.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @A. Cedano por tu ayuda.
He separado los datos en un nodo `tienda` donde cada una se guarda con un `push()` para crear un idendificador único a cada una.

Cada tienda está relacionada con su empresa a través del atributo `empresa` donde se guarda la key de su empresa.

Ahora bien, cuando intento buscar las tiendas que pertenecen a una empresa lo estoy haciendo con el siguiente código, pero no me devuelve ninguna coincidencia:

```
String keyEmpresa = "-LzVv-9gfDb0alZX5kBg";
DatabaseReference tablaTiendas = firebase.getReferenciaNodo("tienda");
 tablaTiendas.orderByChild("empresa").equalTo(keyEmpresa).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```

La estructura de la BD es la siguiente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema estaba en el ```addListenerForSingleValueEvent```.  Lo he sustituido por un ```addValueEventListener``` y ahora funciona correctamente.